12 volvo s60 t6 starting to misfire once upto temp
Please help! I have a 2012 Volvo s60 t6. I found the car misfiring #2. I looked and found a ripped PCV diaphragm. Replaced and car ran fine for 4 days. Today driving it up to temp and started misfiring again. Only seems to happen once warm. Plugs and coils where replaced recently. Any help would be great. I'm thinking injector but not sure how to remove to check. Someone said pressure from fuel rail needs released first. Not sure if that's the case. Please help!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you read the codes? If so, what are the exact codes from the ECU?

Yes getting misfire #2

Code is #302...

Two things: 1st, you may be right it could be a bad injector, but usually bad injectors don't get worse when heated. 2nd, heat then misfire sounds a lot more like a bad coil. Yes, even a new coil could be causing issues. For starters, try swapping out the #2 coil with one relatively near to it to see if the misfire stays at #2 or moves with the coil.

Before anything else, check the compression on cylinder #2 and compare it with the other cylinders.
